Are sentences like 'How odd that is!' SOV and can sentences like that be made with verbs besides 'to be'? What is 'how' exactly in these sentences?
Today while texting my friend, I decided to jocularly send 'How very queer you are!' To me, this sentence sounds correct, but I can't quite understand how it works. Is English not an SVO language? Why would the complement precede the subject and the verb? This looks like an OSV/SOV sentence to me. Further, when 'How' is removed, the sentence suddenly sounds off.

Very queer you are.


Odd that is.

I can imagine such sentences being used in, say, a poem, but it doesn't seem to me to be a grammatical construction. Or might these sentences actually be correct, and would that suggest that English can be OSV/SOV? What is the grammatical function of 'How'? Is it some sort of adverb? Or perhaps an interjection?
Is this construction acceptable with other verbs?

Him you killed!


The dancing lady from afar I had seen, then you approaching her with ill-intent I witnessed.

Are these sentences acceptable? Can 'how' be used before them too?

How him you killed!


How the dancing lady from afar I had seen, then you approaching her with ill-intent I witnessed!


Without the "how" you sound like Yoda...
